# How to pragmatically add a dynamic amount of fragments to an activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an activity with a layout file as follows:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:gravity="top" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/foodItemActvity_linearLayout_fragments"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

   //>>>> Fragments to go here

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.35"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="orderFoodItemClicked"
        android:text="Order this Item Now" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="backToMenuItemClicked"
        android:text="Back To Menu" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I then have 5 fragments already coded each with their own layout files and classes, Which are irrelevant for now.
say they are called for this example:

fragment1.java
fragment2.java
fragment3.java

I want to know how I can dynamically add fragments to the linear layout as specified as above. From my research it seems i need a Fragment manager and a LayoutInflater but I am no sure of how to do this.

So far I have this:

```
LinearLayout fragmentsLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.foodItemActvity_linearLayout_fragments);

    for(int i=0; i < noOfFragments;i++){
        //Add fragment to fragmentsLayout
    }
```

Now I am just not sure on how to go about adding the certain fragments i want?

EDIT: 
And how do I specify details such as layout params for the fragment?

Answer (score 1):

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
for(int i=0; i < noOfFragments;i++){
       ft.add(R.id.foodItemActvity_linearLayout_fragments, fragments[i], "fragment tag" + i);
}
ft.commit();
```

Comment: IT compiles but it doesnt show any of the fragments:  `ImageFragment fb = new ImageFragment(); 

  ft.add(R.id.foodItemActvity_linearLayout_fragments, fb, "fragment" + fragCount);
  fragCount++;
  ft.commit();`

Comment: @Zapnologica what if you add just 1 fragment? Are you sure that fragments are inflating correctly?

Comment: Im noticing its asking mt if i want to use `support.v4.app.` or just normal android. When importing, Which must I use?

Comment: @Zapnologica use support.v4.app if you want support for Android before  Api 11

Comment: If I use v4 then `fragTransaction = fragMan.beginTransaction();` doesnt work. I changed everything to support.app and it compiles. But still no fragment in the display. Can i call `ft.comit` multiple times?

Comment: @Zapnologica yes you can. Check if onCreateView in fragment is executing.

Comment: Gaswel I have this working: `fragTransaction.add(R.id.foodItemActvity_linearLayout_fragments, frag1, "fragment" + fragCount);` But now what do I do if the linear layout id being created pragmatically and not alread existing in a xml file?

Comment: @Zapnologica layout.setId(id); and inside fragTransaction.add use that id.

Comment: It wants an Int as a input and not a String. Must I just use a random int?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the Android developers guide for fragments. It explains how to manage fragments programmatically. http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html